Refactor Expression Body Members c#
I have a class with a bunch of expression body members that really seem like they should be based on a shared inner class but I can't think of a way to refactor/group them.
public decimal SalesTotalCurrent => GoalsDepartmentSalesRows.Sum(x => x.SalesCurrent) ?? 0;
public decimal SalesTotalGoal => GoalsDepartmentSalesRows.Sum(x => x.SalesGoal) ?? 0;
public decimal SalesTotalLast => GoalsDepartmentSalesRows.Sum(x => x.SalesLastYear) ?? 0;
public decimal SalesTotalTrend => TrendPeriodDays == 0 ? 0 : (int?)((TrendTotalSales / TrendPeriodDays) * Days) ?? 0;

public decimal QuantityTotalCurrent => GoalsDepartmentSalesRows.Sum(x => x.QuantityCurrent) ?? 0;
public decimal QuantityTotalLast => GoalsDepartmentSalesRows.Sum(x => x.QuantityLastYear) ?? 0;
public decimal QuantityTotalGoal => (int)(CustomerCountGoal * IptGoal);
public decimal QuantityTotalTrend => TrendPeriodDays == 0 ? 0 : (int?)((TrendTotalQuantity / TrendPeriodDays) * Days) ?? 0;

public decimal ConversionCurrent => (DoorCountCurrent == 0 ? 0 : (CustomerCountCurrent / DoorCountCurrent)) ?? 0;
public decimal ConversionLast => (DoorCountLast == 0 ? 0 : (CustomerCountCurrent / DoorCountCurrent)) ?? 0;
public decimal ConversionGoal { get; set; }
public decimal ConversionTrend => (TrendTotalDoorCount == 0 ? 0 : (CustomerCountCurrent / TrendTotalDoorCount)) ?? 0;

It's always a group of 4 decimals (soon to be 5) with Current, Last, Goal, Trend, and soon TrendLast.  The calculations change and sometimes one is a settable property.  There's about 7 sets of these 5 values and it feels like the class is getting out of hand.
I want to keep them as expressions in case the underlying values change which I think makes deriving a new inner class impossible since it won't have access.  I can't think of a way to use an interface to simplify this.  Perhaps some way with Func or Expression<Func> but I have no idea how.  Accessing it via something like MainClass.SalesTotal.Current is what I'd like.
Am I just stuck with a nasty list of properties with long names -_-

Nothing nasty about having names that explain themselves. I don't have a problem with the code written, nor do I think it's "getting out of hand".
